# PyroCMS - Inserting image in WYSIWYG

Tags: pyrocms

A fresh install of PyroCMS 3.0 Beta...  In the WYSIWYG editor, if I try to insert an image, the popup gives a 404.  Checking the console, the path is not correct.  I've set the path correctly in /config/app.php but this doesn't change it.  Is there a place to configure the paths used for this field type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: EDIT:  I just found the paths hard coded in the JavaScript.    file_manager.js on line 33 calls the URL for the file manager and line 44 calls the URL for the file uploader.  Neither are referencing any config variable.  I'll submit a report to the developers.   Thanks.

Comment: EDIT AGAIN:  Nope, changing those values don't affect anything.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed - a composer update should do it for you and might want to run `php artisan asset:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Per developer - you need to change two files.  filemanager.js and imagemanager.js, lines 33 and 44 of both.  Add "APPLICATION_URL + " in front of path corrects the problem.